# У меня выдаёт ссылку на чат, а у другого пользователя нет!

Tags: python, aiogram

Сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой. Бот написанный на пайтон, работает прекрасно, но заметил тут одну проблему. Ниже приведены скриншоты, в том числе и частичка кода. Все условие выполняются, но бот не реагирует на другого пользователя.

[image: У меня]

[image: У пользователя]

```
        elif message.text == 'СЫЛЛКА НА ПРИВАТНЫЙ КАНАЛ':
            if db.get_sub_status(message.from_user.id):
                if isinstance(user_status, ChatMemberLeft):
                    expire_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
                    link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(chat_id, expire_date, 1)
                    await message.reply(link.invite_link, parse_mode="HTML")
                elif isinstance(user_status, ChatMemberMember):
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы уже находитесь в канале!")
                elif isinstance(user_status, ChatMemberAdministrator):
                    expire_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
                    link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(chat_id, expire_date, 1)
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы являетесь Амдинистратором в канале.")
                    await message.reply(link.invite_link, parse_mode="HTML")
            else:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Купи подписку")
```

Comment: А `user_status` - это что? И что будет если он не попадает под эти 3 типа?

Comment: Вытаскивает переменную, вроде как. 
https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chatmember.html

Comment: Весь ваш код после elif message.text == 'СЫЛЛКА НА ПРИВАТНЫЙ КАНАЛ': переместить в обработчик добавление нового пользователя в группу

Comment: Можно пример, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По парился над своим вопросом, и нашёл ошибку. В моей условий не было проверка пользователей с ChatBanned, и из-а этого не выдавалась ссылка другому пользователю, который имел этот статус.

```
This object contains information about one member of a chat. Currently, the following 6 types of chat members are supported:

ChatMemberOwner
ChatMemberAdministrator
ChatMemberMember
ChatMemberRestricted
ChatMemberLeft
ChatMemberBanned
```

Всех благодарю, за участие в вопросе!

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).